# How to access a variable from another python file in BGE

Tags: python, scripting

I have the 'distance' variable in the file 'char.py'. I wanted to get the value of this variable in another script. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [register your script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/111415/935) it becomes a module which you can then import in another script.

Comment: I want to access without modules.

Comment: @ElektroJavorski if you don't want a module you can add a game property to an object and access that property from every script. See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14173/935) which gets the current scene and accesses the scenes objects.

Comment: Access a variable through an object in the scene I know. I want to access this variable directly from one script to another, without modules and without variables in objects. But if there is no way, then I will study about modules to see how it works. Thank you!